# Select 2 tables using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query like this :

```
var q2 = from i in dbconnect.tblComplementContracts
                 join b in dbconnect.tblContracts on i.contractId equals  b.contractId
                where (i.complementDate.Value - GetTime()).TotalDays <= _permission
                select i;
```

I want to access both of "i" and "b" fields,For example i tried "select i,b" but it didn't work what should i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type:

```
var q2 = from i in dbconnect.tblComplementContracts
         join b in dbconnect.tblContracts on i.contractId equals  b.contractId
         where (i.complementDate.Value - GetTime()).TotalDays <= _permission
         select new { I = i, B = b};

foreach (var x in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("complementDate:{0} contractId:{1}", 
        x.I.complementDate, x.B.contractId);
}
```